# Bibliography style: sort unsrtnat alphabetically and not by first cited

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I am writing my master thesis, and I would like to have the following style for bibliography:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}
Write something
\citep{bib2} and something other \citep{bib1}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

And the Bibliography.bib file:

```
![@misc{bib1,
    Author = {Author},
    Title = {{title1}},
    URL={http://www.google.com},
    Year = {2015}}

@misc{bib2,
    Author = {XAuthor},
    Title = {{title2}},
    URL={http://www.googleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.com},
    Year = {2015}}][1]
```

And it looks like that:
[image]

But I would like to sort the bibliography alphabetically. When I tried to use apalike as bibliography style then the URL did not recognized as site and the result was something like that:

```
     \documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}
        \usepackage[round]{natbib}
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}

        \begin{document}

        Write something
        \citep{{bib2}} and something other \citep{bib1}

        \bibliographystyle{apalike}
        \bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

And the Bibliography.bib file is:

```
@misc{bib1,
    Author = {Author},
    Title = {{title1}},
    howpublished={http://www.google.com},
    Year = {2015}}

@misc{bib2,
    Author = {XAuthor},
    Title = {{title2}},
    howpublished={http://www.googleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.com},
    Year = {2015}}
```

But the Bibliography looks like that:

[image]

Is there any solution to keep the style from unstrnat but with alphabetical order or use hyperref in the url with apalike style?

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, not as a screen shot

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I updated the question compilable code examples!

Comment: Why not `plainnat` instead of `unsrtnat`?

Comment: You should use the `url` field for urls, as you did in the first MWE. Most bibliography styles interpret it and hyperref makes hyperlinks out of it.